# Assign a list of categories with a parent category

Tags: categories, sql

I imported hundreds of locations and other categories. Now I have a list of locations in categories to which I would like to assign the "Location" category as its parent.

I have tried sql but the structure is a bit too complex. And I looked around for a plugin but with no luck.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The parent field in wp_term_taxonomy links a category with its parent category. Get the id of this "Location" parent category and update the wp_term_taxonomy for every location to link them with its parent one.

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin that is quite useful: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-management-tools for doing what you want to do.